# Multiple galleries on the same HTML page using Magnific popup

Tags: magnific-popup

)

I contact you because I have two photo galleries on the same page (I use *). When I click on a thumbnail of gallery #1 it opens the image in HD but if I navigate threw the popup HD images from gallery #2 are also included.

Any way to edit it so links from gallery #1 only shows HDs from gallery #1 and vice versa ?

Thank you so much

*

```
<div class="gallery-item">
<li class="work-item">
<a class="photo-pop-up" href="xxxx">
<div class="work-image">
<img src="x"/>
</div>
</a>
</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Please format your question and provide more code.